# Python не видит библиотеку после использования интерпретатора conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, библиотеки, conda

**Здравствуйте,** моя проблема заключается в том, что Python не видит библиотеки после использования интерпретатора conda.
Когда-то давно я поставил себе Anaconda и использовал его в своих проектах. Недавно мне понадобилось использовать интерпретатор Python 3.12 из папки */usr/local/bin/python 3.12* Сам  python  работает корректно, но когда я пытаюсь импортировать какую нибудь библиотеку, он выдает ошибку *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named.* Если выбрать интерпретатор conda, то при импорте этой библиотеки в проект все работает штатно. проблема не исчезла после команды pip install

```
    /usr/local/bin/python3.12 /Users/EV/Desktop/test/main.py
[virsi:~/Desktop/test] EV% /usr/local/bin/python3.12 /Users/EV/Desktop/test/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/EV/Desktop/test/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PIL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
[virsi:~/Desktop/test] EV%
```

---

Помимо изменения интерпретатора, необходимо также создать новое виртуальное окружение и загрузить туда нужную библиотеку

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: Активировано какое окружение? Нужно активировать то, в которое поставлена библиотека

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через терминал активировать нужное окружение Python можно так:

```bash
$ source /usr/local/bin/python3.12/bin/activate
```

Уже после этого при вызове `pip` будет вызван `pip` активированного окружения. И устанавливать пакеты он будет в директорию активированного окружения. И если теперь в этом окружении вы запустите Python, то установленные вами библиотеки должны быть на месте.

Однако хорошей практикой является использование виртуального окружения.
Зайдите в директорию своего проекта, где находится исходный код. Можете предварительно выполнить активацию окружения:

```bash
$ source /usr/local/bin/activate
```

Затем создайте локальную версию интерпретатора Python в папке `.venv`, например:

```bash
$ python -m venv .venv
```

Теперь можно активировать созданное окружение:

```bash
$ source .venv/bin/activate
```

И дальше работать с ним, как обычно: устанавливать в него пакеты, удалять ненужные и т.д. Это гораздо удобнее, чем использовать для всего единственный интерпретатор из `/usr`.